# How to mount ExtHDD under Debian OS - NOT an SD card?

Tags: debian, mount

HDD; debian OS; orangepi; 2TB; (SCSI DISK) (WDC WD20 03FZEX-00SRLAO) 
......................

I am trying to mount my 2TB WD hdd. as "mount rw, /dev/sda1 exthdd; mount -o rw /dev/sda1 /media. lsblk: disk recognized. DMESG | TAIL : couldn't mount RDWR b/c of unsupported optional features (400)

"Failed to mount "exthdd". Error mounting /dev/sda1 at media/username/exthdd: command line 'mount -t "ext4" -o uhelper=udisks 2,no dev,nosuid "/dev/sda1" "media/username/exthdd - exited with non-zero exit status32: ; "mount: wrong fstype, bad options, etc etc etc........other"

*****After reading the 'similar' article, I tried the following: 
"turn it off on an already created filesystem" "sudo tune2fs -O ^metadata_csum /dev/sdb1"

Did not work. The aforementioned article talks about an SD CARD, my media is a hdd.

Not able to mount either "ro,noexec" or "rw" on my desktop computer where the hdd was formatted. I was able to mount it to a laptop w/ ubuntu, but was not able to copy, paste, or create a folder as "permission denied". I think this hdd was specifically formatted to be solely used with my username for this desktop, debian OS, computer.

I see to format external media, do the following... You'll see where it says "chown" that it asks for my username. I'm wondering if I can do something to remove my username from the hdd (if it's on there) so it will work on other systems.....??????

Thanks.

Comment: mounting: "mount -o ro,noexec /dev/sda1 /exthdd; mount -o ro,noexec /dev/sda1 /media; mount -o rw /dev/sda1 /exthdd; mount -o rw /dev/sda1 /media

Comment: Thanks. Which would you recommend? Which would least likely, if either, to cause a potential problem with the files? To create a ext4 filesystem without this feature: sudo mke2fs /dev/sdb1 -O ^metadata_csum      
Or turn it off on an already created filesystem: 
sudo tune2fs -O ^metadata_csum /dev/sdb1  I think I already have a filesystem, so I am thinking option 2. Thx.

Comment: Yes, you already have a filesystem that uses a feature that is too new for the OS version on your OrangePI. You'll have to take the disk back to the system that created it, switch that feature off, and then try again mounting it with your OrangePI. Using `mke2fs` would definitely destroy any existing files.

Comment: I tried this, didn't work:  sudo tune2fs -O ^metadata_csum /dev/sdb1; I changed sdb1 to my sda1. I also tried the exthdd on ubuntu on a laptop. The laptop didn't find it - nothing in lsblk.

Comment: Since `lsblk` is not showing the disk, check `dmesg` for related errors.

Comment: ER: "ipv6: link not ready; exthdd hooked up to it for 20+ minutes. Proc_ thermal: unsupported event; "ata 1.00: configured for UDMA/133; ata1 sata link up to 6GB's; ss status 133 scontrol 300; r8169: link down; rf kill: input handler disabled; error CPU pipe A FIFO underrun;

Comment: Alternatively, install a Debian version on your OrangePi that's new enough to deal with the ext4 filesystem on the external disk.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! If I download the newest debian version to my desktop orangepi, what will I need to do to get it onto an sd card? I remember using windows to get the original debian to an sd card, but i longer have windows. Thanks.

Comment: Just realized something... I am not using Debian, I am using the following: Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS; Kernel: Linux 3.4.113-sun8i. When I first created the exthdd, it was formatted to ext4 before any files were added. But maybe I was using Debian then, and now Ubuntu. The "ID LIKE" = Debian.